# How to force to use overflow menu instead of native menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have just switched to ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0. After upgrade on my Android 2.3.4 overflow menu was removed. Instead native menu is used.

How can i fix that and force ActionBarSherlock to use overflow menu?

The same issue was reported for Galaxy S3 that run Android ICS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ForceOverFlow style was removed from 4.2. Jake made a comment about why he removed it in one of his G+ posts. 
Someone had asked him if there was a reason for removing the ForceOverflow style and he replied:

"Yes. They should have never been there in the first place and they created inconsistency across API levels. An ICS device with a hardware menu key does not show an overflow so neither should a pre-ICS device."

He also goes on to say "ActionBarSherlock's goal is consistency across API levels. This is the same reason we can't fix some fundamental bugs that appear in the ICS+ action bar."

For the full thread checkout https://plus.google.com/u/0/108284392618554783657/posts/L7nsqBiAtsk

Answer (score 0):

You can use my ActionBarSherlock library, I wanted the function too, so I manually added it in. It's version 4.2. https://github.com/ajws7036/abs42-forceoverflow